# how to set the value of selected dropdown in php?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trouble to set the value of selected option value in 
PHP. At the time of fetching data in MySQL i haven't set the selected value 
of dropdown in PHP.

```
function get_document_name($documents_name)
{
    $output = "";
    foreach ($documents_name as $small_letter => $cap_letter) {
        $selected = ($document_name == $cap_letter) ? 'selected' : '';
        $output .= "<option value='".$small_letter."'".$selected.">".$cap_letter."</option>";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: The variable `$document_name` is not defined in the context of this function. Also I think you want to compare `$small_letter` to `$document_name`, as thats tje value of your options

Comment: Add a space in front of the word selected ... as in `' selected'`.

Comment: Hey prehfeldt! $document_name is an argument because this function is call into javascript.

Comment: No, `$document_name` is _not_ an argument for that function. `$documents_name` is. In the scope of that function, `$document_name` is undefined. I also don't know what you mean by _"this function is call into javascript"_?

Answer (score -1):

Try using below solution. If your if condition doesn't matches, then display normal select option and if matches, then show selected.

```
function get_document_name($documents_name)
{
    $output = "";
    foreach ($documents_name as $small_letter => $cap_letter)
    {
        if( $document_name != $cap_letter )
        {
            $output .= "<option value='".$small_letter."'>".$cap_letter."</option>";
        }
        else
        {
            $output .= "<option value='".$small_letter."' 'selected'='selected'>".$cap_letter."</option>";
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: The variable `$document_name` does not appear to be defined.

Comment: @showdev May be he hasn't put full code. It should be defined before the function. He just asked about how to set selected dropdown and I have answered in his format. Main part of my answer is only **if condition**. There is no need to DownVote this answer. IF he gets the solution using this if condition then it is good.

Comment: Maybe so, and that's a great question to ask the OP. However, as mentioned by @MagnusEriksson, the OP is already using the `selected` attribute. Also, attribute names shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: Yes. He is using `selected` attribute. But it's not in proper format. It should be `'selected'=$selected` in that case. I am using the same format as per my answer and I am always getting my selected values from dropdown.

Comment: [Empty attribute syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty) is valid (unless it's XML). Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jruw0ck3/).